# Adapted Stochastic Process intuitions in previous answers seem misleading

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

## Set up

Given a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}, \{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\in T})$ people seem to say that the intuitive meaning of the stochastic process $\{X_t\,:\, t\in T\}$ being **adapted** to the filtration is that it is non-anticipating/can't see into the future or any variation of this concept.

I feel that is wrong and actually misleading. Can somebody help?

## Reasoning

Here is my reasoning: When we require $\{X_t\}$ to be adapted to $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ all we are requiring is that $X_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable for all $t\in T$. However, and this is the important part, we are **not** saying that $X_t$ is **not** $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$-measurable for $\tau> t$.

Often on this site people say that $X_t$ being $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable means that observing $X_t$ can **only** reveal information contained in $\mathcal{F}_t$. I don't think this is correct, it **can* reveal information contained in $\mathcal{F}_t$, but, as far as I know, there is nothing there that stops $X_t$ being also $\mathcal{F}_{t+1}$-measurable, for instance. If that was the case, it could reveal information contained in $\mathcal{F}_{t+1}$ but not in $\mathcal{F}_t$.

Unless $X_t$ being $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable **excludes** $X_t$ being $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ measurable for all $\tau > t$, then I think the intuition is misleading. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Hint: a filtration is assumed to be increasing: ${\cal F}_t\subset {\cal F}_\tau$ for all $\tau>t\,.$ Hence we *are* saying that the adapted $X_t$ *is* ${\cal F}_\tau$-measurable.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you! I think the point is that we fix the target measurable space!

Comment: The  measurable space on which the process $(X_t)$ is defined is $(\Omega,{\cal F})$ *plus* a filtration $({\cal F}_t)$ of increasing sub-$\sigma$-algebras of ${\cal F}\,.$ What has this to do with the "target" measurable space in the space where $X$ takes its values? I do not know much about machine learning but I have a hard time to believing that it requires to revolutionize those basic definitions.

Comment: I’ve explained it in my answer, the fact that the domain of the random variables is the whole of $\mathsf{X}$ makes sure that it would be useless to assume measurability with respect to a larger sigma algebra

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing about the full solution in my [Measure Theory for Machine Learning](https://maurocamaraescudero.netlify.app/post/2024-02-16-measure-theory-for-machine-learning-and-diffusion-models/), simply search for "Intuition for measurability" and then go to the section for stochastic processes (still a work in progress).

The idea is that if we define $\mathrm{X}:\Omega\to\mathsf{X}$ as a $(\mathcal{F}_t, \mathcal{X})$-measurable random variable then we are specifying the target measurable space $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X})$. By definition **any** set $\mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{X}$ has preimage in $\mathcal{F}_t$. This means that if we now take a larger sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}_{t+1}\supset\mathcal{F}_t$ then there will be no set $\mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{X}$ such that $\mathrm{X}^{-1}(\mathsf{A})\in\mathcal{F}_{t+1}\backslash\mathcal{F}_t$.

Therefore we could say that $\mathrm{X}$ **could** is $\mathcal{F}_{t+1}$-measurable but $\mathrm{X}$ would still not reveal any information contained in $\mathcal{F}_{t+1}$.

---

For reference, I am using the following definition

> **Random Variable**: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X})$ be a measurable space. We say that a function $\mathrm{X}:\Omega\to\mathsf{X}$ is a $(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{X})$-measurable random variable if
> $$
> \mathrm{X}^{-1}(\mathsf{A})\in\mathcal{F} \qquad\qquad\qquad\forall\, \mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{X}.
> $$

Comment: When $X$ is ${\cal F}_t$-measurable it is ${\cal F}_{t+1}$-measurable. It is correct that $X$ is insensitive to newly arriving information that is contained only in ${\cal F}_{t+1}\setminus {\cal F}_t\,.$ No probabilist that I had the privilege of getting to know has ever claimed something different.

Comment: @KurtG. what you say must be right because people don’t mention this in lecture notes. However, as a newby, I find it helpful to say it explicitly. I suppose sigma algebras are a bit abstract and at times it’s unclear to me the intuition behind them